# Two networks over one UTP cable

Tags: networking, router

I have a networking question. I have only one UTP cable between two rooms, and two networks I need to get through that cable.

## Situation outline

**Bedroom**

1 rasbery pi (no wifi)

1 tv setupbox (provided by my ISP)

**Main room**

1 router (provided by my ISP) with two networking ports
 - Port A for WLAN
 - Port B for TV

1 10/100/1000 switch (connected to routers port A)

1 NAS (connected to switch)

## Problem

**I only have ONE UTP cable between the two rooms**, and adding another would be a PITA. RasberyPI (a very old one) also does not like any wifi dongles I give it. (did not know support was so bad :/)

If I plug the UTP cable connecting the rooms into Routers port B (for TV), and add a switch in the bedroom and connect both the rasbery pi and the TV to it, the TV will work. My PI will get an 93.XXX.XXX.XXX IP address. The PI is (expectedly) unable to find a path to my NAS.

My internal network works on the 192.168.1.XXX namespace.

Note: I have no control over the router - port forwarding and WiFi password management is done on their online dashboard.

## Solutions I have tried

I've called my ISP. They said they can push the TV into my LAN, but that would prevent me from watching HD channels and would get bad quality overall. They've advised me to either use a second cable or put it on wifi.

## Question

So, is there a solution to my problem that is cheaper/simpler/quicker than laying another cable or ordering a PI compatible wifi dongle online (and waiting a few weeks for delivery)?

What happens if I just plug Routers port TV port into the switch? Since the setupbox relies on DHCP, will it be able to find the right network?

( I should note my networking knowledge is quite limited)

Comment: Are your switches managed switches and do they support VLAN's, or are they just dumb switches? If they are not managed (ie. dumb switches with no management interface), I wouldn't recommend anything other than running a new cable or getting a WiFi adapter since you would be placing subnets with independent DHCP servers in the same broadcast domain, very bad idea.

Comment: Of course, if you can get your hands on 10/100 switches, you could just cut the ends of the cable off, and put 2 pair on each end in a RJ45 connector. Pins 1, 2, 3, and 6 are all that is needed for 10/100 ethernet.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/351934/how-to-get-two-separated-connections-on-one-cable

Comment: You could use the existing cable to pull two new cables through. In that case, it would be advisable to get higher-quality shielded cables, preferably CAT6/7.

Comment: Unfortunately can't use the cable to pull new one through - it's a 50 year old apartment block - the cable was put into a drilled hole and "plastered" over.

Both switches are "dumb"/unmanaged switches. 

Interesting solution acejavelin, and thanks for the link"